# XSL disable-output-escaping removes whitespaces

Tags: xslt

Part of the XML:

```
<text><b>Title</b> <b>Happy</b></text>
```

In my XSL I have:

```
<xsl:value-of select="text" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

My output becomes

```
**TitleHappy**
```

My spacing went missing - there's supposed to be a space between `</b>` and `<b>`.

I tried `normalize-space()`, it doesn't work.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Your example is working for me. What xml parser and xslt processor are you using, maybe the parser is already stripping the whitespace before the transformation is calles?

Comment: Works for me, too. Your question is missing a small but significant detail, obviously.

Comment: when i set disable-output-escaping="no"
my output becomes <text><b>Title</b> <b>Happy</b></text>
I am still trying to see if there is any relevant information

Comment: I think you need to post more context. Set up a minimal but complete sample that actually reproduces the problem for you, and then post it here. The key is *minimal* - recude the code to the absolute minimum that is still failing.

Comment: This is the complete xsl sample code:

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl"
               xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match = '/'>
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="item">
         <xsl:value-of select="description"  disable-output-escaping="yes" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

With output escaping results:
<b>Title</b> <b>Happy</b>
Without output escaping results:
TitleHappy

Spacing is missing.

Answer (score 1):

if you want whitespace from an xsl, use:
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>

whitespace is only preserved if its recognized as a text node (ie: " a " both spaces will be recognized)

whitespace from the orignal source xml has to be preserved by telling the parser (for example)

parser.setPreserveWhitespace(true);

Comment: So I supposed that the space in between the <b> and </b> is not preserved as it is not recognised as a text node? Anyway to go about preserving it and showing it as output ?

Comment: i was mistook your source as xsl (so the xsl:text method wont work). i am afraid that the xml parser removes the whitespace in your source-xml. if you add any other non-whitespace char it will be recognized as textnode and thus preserve the whitespace (at least once). I would take a close look to the options of your xml parser and make him preserve whitespace. Otherwise a &#160; (or &nbsp; - nonbreaking space) is the only thing that would help.

Answer (score 0):

As your outputting HTML you could substitute your space with a non-breaking space

Comment: Thanks. I am currently using your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any control over the generation of the original XML? If so, you could try adding xml:space="preserve" to the text element which should tell the processor to keep the whitespace.

```
<text xml:space="preserve"><b>Title</b> <b>Happy</b></text>
```

Alternatively, try looking at the "xsl:preserve-space" element in XSLT.

```
<xsl:preserve-space elements="text"/>
```

Although I have never used this personally, it might of some help. See [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/XSL/el_preserve-space.asp) for more information.

Comment: I have no control over the original XML. =(
I tried preserve-space, it doesn't work. Found out it is a default setting anyway.
The space disappeared only when the bold tags are used.
<text>Title Happy</text> still return me Title Happy
Weird.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for everyone's input.
Currently I am using MattH suggestion which is to test for space and substitue to non-breaking space. Another method I thought of is to test for "</b> <b>" and substitue with " </b><b>". The space contain within a bold tags are actually output. Both methods worked. Don't know what the implications are though. And I still can't figure out why the spacing is removed when it is found between 2 seperate bold tags.